# How can I override autowired symfony service?

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony4

I'm working on a Symfony 4 projet and I have read [Symfony documentation about autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

My problem is not really about autowiring but importted files.

[This Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/import.html) says that you can import your services in many files.

In my project, I have the `service.yaml` in the `config` folder which import all services in `services` folder

```
imports:
    - { resource: './services/admin.yaml'}
    - { resource: './services/front.yaml'}
    - { resource: './services/core.yaml' }

services:
    _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
```

So i need to override a service autowiring because it has two strings in constructor and I need to wire those arguments manually

```
extranet.form.data_subscriber.remove_empty_reference_fields:
    class: Extranet\Admin\Form\DataSubscriber\RemoveEmptyFieldsSubscriber
    arguments:
        $collectionName: references
        $childName: name
Extranet\Admin\Form\DataSubscriber\RemoveEmptyFieldsSubscriber: '@extranet.form.data_subscriber.remove_empty_reference_fields'
Extranet\Admin\Form\DataSubscriber\RemoveEmptyFieldsSubscriberInterface: '@Extranet\Admin\Form\DataSubscriber\RemoveEmptyFieldsSubscriber'
```

But now if I put this service directly in my `services.yaml` at the end of file it works.

My question is, how I can override autowiring with services not configured directly in the `services.yaml`

Let me know if you can help me, thanks

**EDIT**

I already tried to put the `imports` part at the end of `services.yaml` file

Comment: I struggled with a similar problem some days ago and found a better solution: decorate the service instead, then it's picked up automatically

Comment: Can you give me an example of that ? Or maybe a link through the symfony doc ?

Comment: https://stovepipe.systems/post/service-decoration-in-practice is one example

Comment: Ok thank you, I added decorates options in my service configuration and it seems to work. I have to admit it's kind of weird to have class and decorates options which points to the same class

Comment: Why do you decorate the same class?

Comment: Was wondering the same thing.  It's not clear to me what the original problem is.

Comment: I think I don't have the knowledge about this pattern. So if I understand correctly, I have to create another class which takes the role of decorator of my existing service ? 
I will try to learn more about it but I don't have enough time right now

Comment: Are you getting "unable to autowire service" type messages?  If so that is an easy fix.

Comment: Yeah it was this error. I read the article about the decorate pattern and in my opinion this is a way to replace an existing service just by extending it. But yes, using `decorates: Namespace\To\Service` worked

Comment: I think the core problem is that you still have the resource: '../src/*' section in your original config/services.yaml file.  This causes autowire to wire up any class it encounters even if one of your imported services file also deals with it.  When using multiple service files you typically need to remove this section completely or mess around with exclude.  Here is an example: https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/config/services.yaml

Comment: Ok I see what you mean I will try this solution or simply remove the auto creation of services and create each service in my yaml files
Thanks for your answer !